# caching + parallelization/vectorization in python JIT

Tags: python, numba, jit, memoization, jax

I want to write a program which has both a lot of repetitive expensive calculation and "embarrassingly parallel" procedures. For example,

For example,

```
global_array: np.ndarray

def expensive_calc(param1, param2)
    return np.convolve([param1, param2], global_array)


def repetitive_calc():
    params = np.random.ranom_integers(0, 5, size=(200,2))
    result = []
    for pair in params:
        result.append(expensive_calc(*params))
    return result
```

It seems to be desirable to do numba.jit on repetitive_calc, but lru_cache on expensive_calc, but numba does not seem to support caching. I came across this issue 3-year-old https://github.com/numba/numba/issues/4062 and there doesnt seem to be any progress since then. I also tried JAX, which does support caching, but JAX array manipulation on CPUs does not seem to have very impressive performance for this kind of problem.

Are there any good ways to write JIT compiled+intermediate-result-cached programs in python now?

Comment: Could you give an example that is closer to your problem? Because it's difficult to see how something is an issue here. You could write a simple cache with a dictionary for example but what would the keys be?

Comment: @NathanFurnal This example I gave is pretty close as a minimal working example. Indeed I could use a numba.typed.Dict and accompany every function with a class/object which holds the cache dictionary, but 1. numba class is still experimental feature which doesn't suppport all the compilation arguments, 2. it is really a lot of code repetition

Comment: Do you know the number of iterations of repetitive calc in advance per chance?

Comment: @NathanFurnal yes. The parameters parsed to the expensive calculation are  floats from a small set.

Comment: Details are missing and they are critical to answer the question. Jitting the parent function is useless if the children is not since it is not the expensive function. In fact, Numba for example does not even allow this unless you use the objmode which is  basically useless (only useful for debugging purpose and not performance). The main part is `expensive_calc` which is AFAIK not the actual funciton used in your program so we cannot do much on it either. Not to mention the type, dimensionality, shape and stride of the global array is also unknown and `ranom_integers` does not exists...

Comment: Note that, currently, this code can be certainly optimized by merging the small kernels together possibly using a spectral transformation and then apply the final filter in parallel. The spectral transform certainly worth it only if the filter are predefined constants or specific mathematical properties.

Comment: thank you @JérômeRichard for your suggestions. I will try to come up with a more concrete example.